# Maximizing a function defined in terms of meta notation

Tags: discrete-optimization

Let $f : \mathbb{N}^n \to \mathbb{N}$ be the function defined by

$$f(w) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^m 1_A(M_iw)$$

where $M_i$ is the $i^{\text{th}}$ row of a matrix $M\in \text{Mat}_{m\times n}(\mathbb{N})$, $w$ is a column vector in $\mathbb{N}^n$, and

$$1_A(n) := \begin{cases}1 & n\in A\\0 & n \notin A\end{cases}$$

For concreteness, you can fix $A$ to be any set such that $|A| = 1$ and $M$ to be any nontrivial matrix.

How would one approach maximizing $f$? It seems like trial and error is the only approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to handle your new $A$ set with $37m$ binary variables and $m+n$ integer variables.  Let binary decision variable $x_{i,j}$ indicate that $M_i w = j\pmod {37}$.
Then you want to maximize $\sum_{i=1}^m x_{i,15}$ subject to:
\begin{align}
M_i w &= 37p_i + \sum_{j=0}^{36} j\ x_{i,j} &&\text{for $i\in\{1,\dots,m\}$}\\
\sum_{j=0}^{36} x_{i,j} &= 1&&\text{for $i\in\{1,\dots,m\}$}\\
x_{i,j} &\in \{0,1\} &&\text{for $i\in\{1,\dots,m\}, j\in\{0,\dots,36\}$}\\
p_i &\in [0,36m] \cap \mathbb{Z}&&\text{for $i\in\{1,\dots,m\}$}\\
w_k &\in \mathbb{N}&&\text{for $k\in\{1,\dots,n\}$}
\end{align}

Comment: This is orders of magnitude (quite literally) simpler than what I had been doing before. I've changed this to the accepted answer because it's a lot neater and answers my question more precisely.

Comment: It should actually be $37m$ binary variables and $m$ integer variables, no?

Comment: Yes, corrected to $37m$ and $m+n$ (including $w$).

Answer (score 2):

Let $A=\{a\}$.  You can solve the problem via mixed integer linear programming as follows. For $i\in\{1,\dots,m\}$, introduce binary decision variables $x_i$, $y_i$, and $z_i$, and let $\ell_i$ and $u_i$ be constant lower and upper bounds on $M_i w $.  The problem is to maximize $\sum_{i=1}^m y_i$ subject to constraints:
\begin{align}
\ell_i x_i + a y_i + (a+1) z_i \le M_i w &\le (a-1)x_i + a y_i + u_i z_i &&\text{for $i\in\{1,\dots,m\}$}\\
x_i+y_i+z_i&=1 &&\text{for $i\in\{1,\dots,m\}$}\\
x_i &\in \{0,1\} &&\text{for $i\in\{1,\dots,m\}$}\\
y_i &\in \{0,1\} &&\text{for $i\in\{1,\dots,m\}$}\\
z_i &\in \{0,1\} &&\text{for $i\in\{1,\dots,m\}$}
\end{align}
If $x_i=1$, then $M_i w < a$.
If $y_i=1$, then $M_i w = a$.
If $z_i=1$, then $M_i w > a$.

Comment: Thanks! This was a simplification of the case I'm working with, which is where $A = \{k|\exists p \in \mathbb{N}^{\leq 36m}:k=15+37p\}$. I think I see how to generalize your approach to this case, but it's messy: you would need decision variables $x_{i_1},\dots,x_{i_{36m}}$ and similarly for $y$ and $z$. Is there an approach for modular arithmetic which doesn't involve (3)(36m) decision variables?

Comment: Sorry, it actually only requires (2)(36m)+1 decision variables, but that's still absurdly many.